# If first field matches between files, replace next line with second field from other file

Tags: awk

I'm trying to replace lines in a file with strings from another file, if I have an ID match between files.

File 1 contains information in groups of four lines. The line with ID has several columns, the other lines only contain a single column:

```
ID1   some   other   information
ABCD
x
123
ID2   some   other   information
EFGH
x
456
```

File 2 contains information in two columns:

```
ID1   abcd
ID2   efgh
```

I want to replace the next line after ID line of file 1 with the second column of file 2 if ID matches between files, but keep all other information intact, so that output becomes:

```
ID1   some   other   information
abcd
x
123
ID2   some   other   information
efgh
x
456
```

I'm trying to solve this in awk by creating an array with the information from file 2, but I don't understand how to apply this to the next line in the file as I need it to be:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a{<NEXT LINE>=a[$1]}1' file2 file1
```

I am new to this, and thankful of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR == NR{arr[$1]=$2;next} cur_val != ""{$1=cur_val; cur_val=""} arr[$1] != "" {cur_val=arr[$1]}{print}' file2 file1
```

Well making it a little more clearer,

```
#! /bin/bash

awk '{
    if (FNR == NR) {
        arr[$1]=$2
        next
    } 
    else
    if (cur_val != "") {
        $1=cur_val
        cur_val=""
    } 
    else
    if (arr[$1] != "") {
        cur_val=arr[$1]
    }
    print
}' file2 file1
```